# What's the intended way to turn a NSString into a NSDecimalNumber with two decimal places?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, type-conversion, nsdecimalnumber

I'm currently using the following methodology to turn a `NSString` number (like `@"123.456"`) into a `NSDecimalNumber` after rounding (like `123.46`), but it feels hacky. Is there a more intended solution?

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber*)decimalNumberForString:(NSString*)str accuracy:(NSUInteger)accuracy
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = accuracy;
    formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp;
    NSNumber *numberVersion = [formatter numberFromString:str];
    return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:numberVersion.decimalValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at NSDecimalNumberHandler and NSDecimalNumber's

`-decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`

method.

You can create a NSDecimalNumber with your unedited string, then create a new NSDecimal number that's rounded according to the rules you set on NSDecimalNumberHandler.

There's no need to edit your input string.

Comment: `NSDecimalNumberHandler` has only [4 options for rounding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSRoundingMode). Is there any way I can use [the ones used in `NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode)?

Comment: No, so you need to assess whether the NSDecimalNumberHandler rounding suits your needs. NSRoundPlain should really be called NSRoundHalfAwayFromZero. What kind of rounding do you need to do?

Comment: Currently, `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp`, but perhaps a custom flip/flopping of that and `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfDown` (["round half alternatingly"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Alternating_tie-breaking)).

Comment: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp should be the same as NSRoundPlain. They both round half away from zero (which is technically rounding negative numbers down). Round half even (either class) is useful if you're trying to level out compounded rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString:), like this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123.456"];
```

The number of decimal places only affects the string representation of the number; once the number is stored in an `NSDecimalNumber` object it can be formatted back to a string in any way you desire.